# Mcafee update blocked silverlight and the future of the Silverlight Technology

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-runtime, mcafee

Today, while I'm running a Silverlight project in the Internet Explorer by pressing F5 in Visual Studio 2012 in my Windows 8 machine, I found that McAfee started to block Silverlight XAPs (Which is loaded by Prism).

This leads me to think again about the future of Silverlight. I'm at the beginning of my LOB Application. Should I stop what I like to work in Silverlight and return back to WPF. I which that I can continue to develop in Silverlight until Windows 8 becomes rich like Silverlight. That is why I limit the Model and MVVM to PCL to be easier to be ported to WinRT in the future. Using await async and so...

Please advise me which is better for a LOB application that will run in three countries throw the Internet. Should I continue in Silverlight for zero deployment, or work in WPF or even Windows Forms and use clickonce?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that McAffee blocked something has NOTHING to do with it's long term future. McAfee is nobody, they don't determine whether or not a specific technology can be used or not, or will be used in the future.

Silverlight `seems` to have reached a dead end, due to Microsoft realizing that if they create a multi-platform application environment, people might just stop using Windows.

WPF also seems to have been abandoned in favor or WinRT XAML, but of course WinRT XAML is not an option for us developers at the moment, simply because it is Windows 8-only, and our customers don't have Windows 8 or greater.

Besides, technically, WinRT-XAML seems to be really inferior to WPF XAML, and lacks many important features.

Of course winforms is completely useless and is not an option, unless you need to run your applications in my grandma's 80386 computer  with an Hercules monochrome monitor 
(exaggeration).

Seriously, that dead technology is not the answer to any of today's challenges. Things that you can do easily in any of the XAML-based technologies are either impossible or require a bunch of horrible hacks in winforms.

I suppose the definitive answer depends a lot on the usage scenario, for example:

- Silverlight makes more sense if you have to publish your application in a web site and have anyone download it and use it.
- WinRT XAML makes sense only if you target Windows 8, or want to create 'metro style' apps.
- WPF makes sense if you want to create Windows Desktop applications, and have them deployed via ClickOnce or Windows Installer  to a more limited and controlled set of users (because it needs installation of the .Net  Framework, which Click-Once can deal with anyways).
- winforms makes no sense whatsoever because it's a completely useless dinosaur technology that doesn't support anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer and sharing your experience with me. I always try keeping WinRT as a strategy planning for each line of code I write. As I wish to migrate my code easily to WinRT in the future. The future is translated to me as may be within two years I may find myself in a situation that we will be targeted to migrate to something like Windows 9.

The best successful migration scenario - as I wish, it could be by increasing the usage of PCL at the client side as much as possible and test in a small piece of WinRT module.

We hope that Microsoft succeed in Windows 9.

I am sadly decided to shift to WPF instead of Silverlight in case that Silverlight depends on browsers that may not be supported in the future. As we here that Chrome, Safari and others are stopping supporting Silverlight. Why should I insist in relaying with such great technology that is dead before it finishes.

The main difficulties I could face in the future migration could be tied to two patterns:
- Prism.Regions: Windows Store has better than that.
- Prism.Modularity: Windows Store has no migration strategy to that.

At least at the moment I'm writing my thoughts Prism for Windows Store are far from implementing Regions and Modularity.

This is not a final answer but a clue of my what I should and should not to do.